# $_product->getAttributeText gives a "Notice: Array to string conversion"

Tags: attributes

Why does `getAttributeText()` is giving a "PHP Notice" from time to time?

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();

// Get new brand name

echo $_product->getAttributeText('new_brand');
```

This breaks the page and gives me following error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion  in /www/sites/mysite/files/html/app/design/frontend/default/bluemoon/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml on line 48 (this template is modified, I know)
```

But it seems the code does not breaks the page for each product.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are trying to print array with `echo`, it only allows string. Please attached output of `var_dump($_product->getAttributeText('new_brand'))` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems related to the `new_brand` attribute structure; can you please perform the following query and past the result here?

```
SELECT a.*, ca.* 
FROM catalog_eav_attribute ca
INNER JOIN eav_attribute a ON a.attribute_id = ca.attribute_id
WHERE entity_type_id = 4 
AND a.attribute_code = 'new_brand'
```